# Space between paragraphs (local)

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I would like to increase the space between two paragraphs only, not for the whole document. For example I want to have something like this

Paragraph1: One paragraph here

Paragraph2: Space between the 1st paragraph and this one, the default option from.

Paragraph3: the 3rd paragraph to have larger/smaller space from the 2nd, than the 2nd has from 1st (for my purpose I want to be larger).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To insert local extra space between paragraphs, LaTeX offers the commands `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, and `\bigskip` which will add space of `\smallskipamount`, `\medskipamount`, and `\bigskipamount` (see the example for the default value of those when using the `article` class). Alternatively, you may add custom extra space with `\vspace{<extent of space>}`, using either (La)TeX units like pt, ex, etc. or a multiple of, e.g., `\baselineskip`. (Note: `\smallskip` & friends internally use `\vspace`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Hello, here is some text without a meaning. This
    text should show, how a printed text will look like at this place.
    If you read this text, you will get no information.}

\begin{document}

\verb|\smallskipamount|: \the\smallskipamount

\verb|\medskipamount|: \the\medskipamount

\verb|\bigskipamount|: \the\bigskipamount

\sometext

\sometext

\medskip

\sometext

\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}

\sometext

\end{document}
```

[image]