# Quotes and scrlttr2 environment - forces permanent indenting

Tags: environments, scrlttr2

I'm seeing unexpected behaviour where using the `quote` environment permanently resets the margins/writing space (not sure what is technically happening) for the remainder of the document using documentclass scrlttr2.  Each subsequent `quote` further reduces the writing space.

Is there a simple fix?  Or is changing documentclass the best solution (annoying but I can mimic the set up another way I'm sure).  See MWE and output below.

[image: Screenshot of the output from the MWE]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4]{scrlttr2}

% Dont forget to read the KOMA-Script documentation, scrguien.pdf

\setkomavar{fromname}{} % your name
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address \\ of \\ Sender}

\setkomavar{signature}{} % printed after the \closing
\renewcommand{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright} % make the signature ragged right

\setkomavar{subject}{} % subject of the letter

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Name and \\ Address \\ of \\ Recipient}

\opening{Dear}  % eg. Hello

Text that is formatted as expected \quote{something in quotes} \\

and then forever after I'm stuck with different indenting\\

Even many paragraphs later \quote{leading to subsequent quotes being even more indented}

and then being stuck even further indented

\closing{Regards} %eg. Regards

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph, it generates bad output and an underfull box warning

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what is your suggested way to force spacing between paragraphs?  The only way I'm familiar with is \\ (perhaps with a length if required), which is what I have always used when I need space.

Comment: `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph does not add _space_ it appends a spurious extra line to the paragraph as if you had gone `\\ SPACE HERE`  but as the line is empty tex warns you it has badness 10000 (which is its _maximum_ level of bad output) just leave a blank line in the source and specify that you want paragraphs offset with vertical space as a document class option to the koma classes, or using the `parskip` package.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @DavidCarlisle.  I think however with how I use them the parskip package actually doesn't have the same effect - as this varies the spacing between all paragraphs rather than specific ones.  Likewise - leaving a blank line leaves some space between paragraphs, but not the extra space I am looking for (I'm usually using both, or specifically using \\[3cm].  Experimenting a bit, it seems you can remove the badness warning by using \\~\phantom{stuff}, which I guess would be a better option.  Thanks for making me aware of this

Comment: `\\~\phantom{stuff},` is even worse than simple `\\ ` as you still get the bad output but no warning. Either way you are not getting vertical space but a "white line of text" this for example will not be dropped at a page break so you will get pages starting one line too low.

Comment: I can see how blank lines at the top of a page would be very annoying - I'll have to look around and see if there is a simple, practical way to get extra space between select paragraphs that doesn't have this problem.

Comment: the documented command to get extra space is `\vspace`

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle - I just went looking and found this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114569/space-between-paragraphs-local , which has a few suggestions, including \vspace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you note in the title `quote` is an environment so has syntax

```
\begin{quote}
stuff here
\end{quote}
```

not `\quote{stuff here}`  However that *just* indents a block quote, you seem to want an inline quotation with quote marks, so the markup should be

```
``stuff here''
```

Comment: this is unrelated to the document class, you would see the same behaviour in `article` or any of the standard classes.

Comment: This seems generally undesirable behaviour (perpetually indenting the rest of the document repeatedly) so I did a bit more searching and found the explanation that  \quote is an internal definition that was never meant to be used directly.

Comment: No quotation marks wanted - the format from \quote{} was what I was after, just without the effect on the rest of the document.

Comment: @Esme_ the behaviour isn't undesirable or specific to quote: you started a quotation but didn't end it so it lasts until the end of the document. You would see the same if you replaced `\quote` by `\bfseries` the rest of the document would go bold, or `\large` or `\color{red}`  etc.